# Inverse engineering time

Tags: design, schematics

I got this circuit from an automatic lightbulb sensor , it basically turns on whenever the IR sesnsor detects movement, I was able to reverse engineer the entire circuit, however this clever bastards deleted the silk screen of one integrated circuit (as usual), I have all the other values (I can measure the smd caps by desoldering and using an LCR metter, I have yet to do it) however I know the answer... but I want to try anyway

How can I identify what kind of circuit is inside this IC?! (top at the mid of the page)

Also if anyone can see some inconsensitencies in the schemmatic all the feedback is welcome I will go for a round 2 tomorow (to check those inconsistencies)

[image]
[image]

After desoldering (I made the scratch by mistake) the IC I found a number below it, but still it doesnt fit any schemmatics online

[image]

If its any help this is the actual product

http://chinastarlux.gmc.globalmarket.com/products/details/st451-infared-motion-sensor-lamp-holder-pir-motion-sensor-light-holder-439377.html

Comment: I don't see any schematic. A lot of IR sensors use a single LM324 which is about the cheapest thing with 14 legs that doesn't move on its own. Please fix the obvious spelling mistakes and capitalization in your question- there are at least 10 instances- more than one per line.

Comment: Were you trying to link to something? If an IC doesn't have a marking, it's possible that it's an ASIC, a custom one (that you can't buy).

Comment: forgot to add the schemmatic sorry

Comment: the IC without labels is the lower one actually it really doesnt seem to have scratches or paint above itself so the chances of it never having any silkscreen seem high

Comment: Smells like a zero-crossing detector/dimmer. Also, the cap drop supply looks a bit strange (although it may be how it's laid out there).

Comment: well yea the product has 2 potentiometers one to control the time the light will be turned on and the other to set the level of light when the bulb should turn (lots of light or few light) they both go to that IC

Comment: Possibly it is a PIC microcontroller 12F629 manufactured by Microtchip Technology Inc http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41190G.pdf

Comment: Is it worth reverse engineering this?  Maybe just design from the start?